# Exception to the "brace your expr expressions" rule. What's going on?

Tags: tcl

I have a number, say 10, in one variable and a string like +1 or -2 in another. I need to evaluate 10+1 or 10-2 in the above cases.

So, I have

```
set foo 10
set garp -1
```

If I do

```
expr $foo $garp
```

all is well (I get 9).

Ah! But in general, you should put braces around the `expr` expression.

```
expr {$foo $garp}
```

fails with `missing operator at _@_ in expression $foo _@_$garp`.

Similarly,

```
expr [concat $foo $garp]
```

works nicely but

```
expr {[concat $foo $garp]}
```

returns `10 -1`.

I don't want to leave the expression unbraced without *really understanding what's going on* as I'm afraid that otherwise I, or someone else, is going to put braces around the expression and the code will stop working.

What's the "correct" way to do this?

Comment: The exception to the “always brace your expressions” rule is when you've got an _expression_ in a variable or returned from a command.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `expr` involves two rounds of substitution.

The first round of substitution is performed by the command parser on those arguments of the `expr` command that are not enclosed in braces. The resulting strings are concatenated (by adding separator spaces between them) into a single expression string, which is then parsed (and later evaluated) by the expression processor.

During parsing, the expression is decomposed into operators and operands. Operands must be delimited with operators. Assuming focus on mathematical expressions (i.e. discarding string operations), an operand may be one of the following:

1. a numeric value
2. a Tcl variable, using standard `$` notation. ***The variable's value will be used as the operand.***
3. a Tcl command enclosed in brackets. ***The command will be executed and its result will be used as the operand.***
4. a parenthesized sub-expression, which is parsed using the same rules.
5. a mathematical function whose arguments are sub-expressions, parsed using the same rules.

Items 2 and 3 correspond to the ***second round of substitution***, which is performed by the expression processor during evaluation. Each substitution performed at this step is expected to yield a numeric value that is directly usable in further evaluation, *without needing to re-parse and re-evaluate it*.

Having all this said, let's look at your examples:

---

```
expr $foo $garp
```

The command processor expands this during the 1st round of substitution to `expr 10 -1`, the expression string after concatenation of the arguments is `{10 -1}`, and the expression processor parses it into a valid expression `10 subtract 1`.

---

```
expr [concat $foo $garp]
```

During the 1st round of substitution the command processor expands this to `expr {10 -1}`, effectively producing the same expression string as in the previous case.

---

```
expr {$foo $garp}
```

The command processor leaves this intact, and the expression processor sees two consecutive operands (corresponding to clause 2 above), without any operator between them.

---

```
expr {[concat $foo $garp]}
```

Again, the 1st round of substitution is not performed. Parsing this expression extracts a single operand `[concat $foo $garp]` corresponding to clause 3. Expression processor evaluates the command and substitutes its result (i.e. the string `"10 -1"`) for the result of the full expression.

---

So the correctly braced version of your expression must read:

```
expr {$foo + $garp}
```

which will be parsed as `$foo add $garp`.

Comment: The `concat` command (effectively) does a `string trim` on each of its arguments and then a `join` on the list, so putting a single space between them all.

Comment: @DonalFellows You are right, thanks. I haven't done Tcl coding for quite a while and confused concat's behaviour with that of append. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Leon and @DonalFellows. I guess the vital factor that I hadn't realised before and don't recall seeing elsewhere is Leon's italicised phrase describing the rules for expression parsing following the list above - _without needing to re-parse and re-evaluate it_. I'm shaken to find a corner of Tcl where I can't rely on my intuition and where replacing a string with a variable containing that string renders a different answer - i.e. `expr {10 -1}` differs from `set str {10 -1}; expr {$str}`.

Comment: @nurdglaw: replacing the string with a variable containing that string is `expr $str`. Replacing the string with a (braced) string containing that string as a variable will always render a different answer.

Comment: Agreed. I guess I'd taken the advice always to brace `expr` expressions a little too simplistically and imagined that I'd seen somewhere it would always come to the same thing. Perhaps the exception that you and Donal highlight ought to be more prominent when the advice is offered - maybe it is and I've never noticed it. (By the way your suggestion that maybe I should rethink the structure of the code is very well made. In this case my satisfaction at omitting two keystrokes (` +`)  led me into error.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

```
expr {$foo + $garp}
```

The rule "always brace your expressions" stems from the fact that it is a good idea to bypass the argument evaluation step and leave the evaluation of the expression string completely to `expr` (because it is more secure<sup>1</sup> and results in more effective bytecode<sup>2</sup>).

For this to work, the string passed to `expr` needs to be legal according to the rules laid out in the `expr` docs (an unbraced expression doesn't have to be legal as long as the argument evaluation step makes it legal). From this follows that anytime you need the argument evaluation to help you create a legal expression string is an exception to the "always brace" rule (and possibly a hint that you need to rethink the structure of your code<sup>3</sup>).

The string `{$foo $garp}` is illegal because variable substitutions can only be operands in an expression, meaning that we have two operands without an operator. The string `"$foo $garp"` is transformed by the argument evaluation into a legal expression as the minus operator is reinterpreted into a subtraction operator.

If you have a bunch of values that you are getting in pairs, `a` and `b`, and you want to add those, `expr $a $b` might work if you are sure that they always have a sign. That's brittle, though. It's better to use one of

```
expr {$a + $b}
tcl::mathop::+ $a $b
expr [join [list $a $b] +]
```

(The first one is the solution we've discussed above. The second one avoids double substitution by using the `+` operator outside of `expr`: the variables are evaluated by the argument evaluator but not by the command. The third variant has all the problems of double substitution and is mentioned mostly for completeness. It's still better than just `expr $a $b`, though.)

Documentation:
[+ (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[Mathematical operators as Tcl commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm)

<sup>1</sup>) The argument evaluator, given hostile arguments, could for instance replace `$foo` in the expression with `[exec rm -rf *]` or whatever you crazy Linux kids call it, and then the command substitution will be performed inside `expr`. This is less likely to happen if you disallow double substitution by bracing the expression.

<sup>2</sup>) The byte compiler can analyze a braced expression and replace the call to `expr` with more efficient inlined calculations. For an unbraced string, the compiler has no other option than to set up a call to `expr` whatever the expression is.

<sup>3</sup>) Seemingly paradoxically, it is *not* a problem to construct an expression by some trusted method and pass it unbraced via a variable (`set myexpr [...] ; expr $myexpr`), because this way you are still in full control of the content of the expression, and you are certainly not depending on the argument evaluator to patch it up for you. You won't get the bytecode optimization, though.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLewerin. That certainly fixes the problem; I'm looking forward to learning what the problem was/is.

Comment: @nurdglaw: sorry, overslept and woke up with a headache. Hopefully the answer will be useful.